# Go to URL not working for URL having # character

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have defined an Action on my Textbox to Go to an URL. For that I have used Go to URL in Action. Below is my code in the Expr.

> ="javascript:void(window.open('"+Parameters!url.Value+"'))"

The issue is if the URL has # character in the Parameter then that URL doesn't work and gives me an error as:

> The 'Team' parameter is missing a value.

I'm aware that Special characters needs to be encoded and I'm trying to replace the # character but that isn't working.

The **Parameters!url.Value** is: https://localhost:80/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reports/End+Dashboard+-+Drilldown&Sprint=10.5&Team=#LetsDoIt&Type=Drilldown

Here you can the see the parameter `Team` has value as `#LetsDoIt`. For demonstrating purpose I'm using this but on live it is coming from Reports Parameters combination. I'm facing issue only if the `Team` parameter has # in its value.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you share "Parameters!url.Value" value ?

Comment: Question updated @jainvikram444

Comment: What have you tried and in what way is it "not working". The words "not working" mean that you have not yet analysed or understood the issue. Before you ask a question, you should understand your issue.

Comment: Please, use replace function for "#" char like:
SELECT REPLACE(column_name, '#', '');

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried this `="javascript:void(window.open('"+Replace(Parameters!url.Value,"#","%23")+"'))"` and it does not worked. When I hit the link by replacing # with %23 then it works because I'm escaping the # character. The same I need to achieve in the Action URL. I'm trying to replace # with %23 but that is not happening.

Comment: @jainvikram444 I'm aware of this method but this would be not be feasible for me as the team name needs to be exactly matched. What if there are 2 teams with name as `#LetsDoIt` and `LetsDoIt`, this would disrupt my logic. And implementing this would take revamp of each and every Stored Procedure linked to my Report.

Comment: You used those words again - "not worked", "not happening". What really happened? Did you get a 404 error? What was the actual final URL that was generated as a result of your javascript. Was it different to a funcitoning URL?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I got what you are asking. I get error message as `The 'Team' parameter is missing a value.` I have updated my question.

Comment: Here's some info for you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8df90ea7-899c-4a3a-a327-12b11e7ae184/parameter-contains-character?forum=sqlreportingservices. Basically you need to go and unencode it on the report side as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution with the help of the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8df90ea7-899c-4a3a-a327-12b11e7ae184/parameter-contains-character?forum=sqlreportingservices) provided by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid).

**Problem** : I replaced `#` with `%23` to encode the `#` but when the URL was clicked the encoded text `%23` was decoded back with `#` which was breaking the link to function.

So, I used double encoding for that purpose, I'm replacing `#` with `%2523` like below :

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"+Replace(Parameters!url.Value,"#","%2523")+"'))"
```

So now when it comes to the URL, it only gets decoded once. So the final URL is :
https://localhost:80/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reports/End+Dashboard+-+Drilldown&Sprint=10.5&Team=%23LetsDoIt&Type=Drilldown
which works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8df90ea7-899c-4a3a-a327-12b11e7ae184/parameter-contains-character?forum=sqlreportingservices

You need to continue using the urlencoding, but you actually need to decode it in the SSRS report.

So, continue to use this:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"+Replace(Parameters!url.Value,"#","%23")+"'))"
```

But then in the actual SSRS report (more or less verbose from the MSDN link)

"Go to Data set, right click -> go to Properties -->go to Parameters tab--> change expression of parameter value to"

```
=Replace(Parameters!Parameter_Name.Value,"%23","#")
```

.. it's saying that in your actual SSRS report you need to recognise the `%23` and change it back to a `#`

Please in future never write 'does not work'. Actually take the time to observe, understand, and describe the issue

Comment: I tried everything possible to make this work but it didn't at that time. I was aware what was the problem but couldn't find a way to that. I wasted an entire day to make this work. Your link helped and I finally implemented it with a more cleaner way than you suggested here. I will post that solution as an Answer soon.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer. Thanks for returning and documenting it - I'm sure this will be helpful to a lot of people